# Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot

I am using rspec-rails, factory_girl_rails and mogoid_rspec gems. After adding factory girl gem, I keep getting the error `Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)` for my user factory. Following are the related code snippets:

In my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'mongoid-rspec', '~> 2.1.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.expand_path('../factories', __FILE__)]

FactoryGirl.find_definitions
require 'support/mongoid'
require 'support/factory_girl'
require 'support/disable_active_record_fixtures'
require 'mongoid-rspec'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) do
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end

  config.include Mongoid::Matchers, type: :model

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean
  end

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name     Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name      Faker::Name.last_name
    email          Faker::Internet.email
  end
end
```

spec/support/factory_girl.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't know if that's a typo, but your factory filename should be plural (`factories/users.rb`) instead of singular (`factories/user.rb`). Check if that helps.

Comment: @ZuzannaSt, thanks but still the same error :(

Comment: maybe you could config your factories paths the other way, placing this line inside your `Rspec.configure do |config|`:

`config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"`

Comment: @ZuzannaSt - Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: could you add your `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: @ZuzannaSt, I have edited my question to include spec_helper.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82618/discussion-between-rads-and-zuzannast).

Answer (score 0):

As we've discussed, I'm pasting my proposition of what you could change in your code (including good practices).

1. Define `factory_girl_rails` gem inside `group :test, :development`.

   ```
   #Gemfile
   group :development, :test do
     gem 'byebug'
     gem 'rspec-rails'
     gem 'factory_girl_rails'
     gem 'faker'
     gem 'mongoid-rspec', '~> 2.1.0'
   end

   group :test do
     gem 'database_cleaner'
     gem 'shoulda-matchers'
   end
   ```
2. Require your support files in one single line instead of multiply
   definitions.

   ```
   # spec/rails_helper.rb 
   ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test' 
   require 'spec_helper' 
   require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__) 
   require 'rspec/rails'

   # Prevent database truncation if the environment is production 
   abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

   Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

   RSpec.configure do |config|   
     config.before(:all) do
       FactoryGirl.reload   
     end

     config.include Mongoid::Matchers, type: :model

     config.before(:suite) do
       DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation   
     end

     config.before(:each) do
       DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].start   
     end

     config.after(:each) do
       DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean   
     end

     config.use_transactional_fixtures = false  
     config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location! 
   end
   ```
3. Create your `.rspec` file (or edit yours if you already have it) to
   `require spec_helper` and `rails_helper` without having to call it manually in every single spec. 
   I'd also suggest for everyone to
   color and format the spec output.

   ```
   # .rspec
   --color
   --format documentation
   --require spec_helper
   --require rails_helper
   ```